# How can I add an object to an array with a specific object in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, object

This is my array `$table`:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Documents {#1523 ▼
    -id: 55
    -uuid: "0b4d53cba2"
    -name: "neu"
    -timestamp: DateTime @1570445917 {#1517 ▶}
    -pages: Pages {#1019 ▶}
    -products: PersistentCollection {#1512 ▶}
    -projects: PersistentCollection {#1509 ▶}
    -members: PersistentCollection {#1506 ▶}
    -documents: PersistentCollection {#1526 ▶}
  }
  1 => Documents {#1521 ▼
    -id: 56
    -uuid: "d87da82cde"
    -name: "zwei"
    -timestamp: DateTime @1570453219 {#1535 ▶}
    -pages: Pages {#1019 ▶}
    -products: PersistentCollection {#1532 ▶}
    -projects: PersistentCollection {#1519 ▶}
    -members: PersistentCollection {#1522 ▶}
    -documents: PersistentCollection {#1488 ▶}
  }
]
```

I try to add to the array with the object `uuid` `0b4d53cba2` the object `bar` with the value `1234`:

```
  if (isset($table->uuid == "0b4d53cba2")){
      $table->{"bar"} = '1234';
    }
```

But it is not added.

Comment: What is the definition of the class called `Documents` as this may have methods to access the data (unless it's defined as being `public`).

Comment: Sounds as though you need to do `if ($table->getUuid() == "0b4d53cba2"){`, then also when you set the value (maybe) `$table->setBar( '1234' );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

working solution:

```
  foreach($table as &$arr){
      if($arr->getUuid() == "0b4d53cba2"){
        $arr->{"bar"} = '1234';
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not added, because your if statement is incorrect

```
if (isset($table->uuid == "0b4d53cba2"))
```

If the `uuid` is `0b4d53cba2` then it will do `isset(true)` (and if not, it will do `isset(false)`).

You have to first check if `uuid` is set and afterwards check the value:

```
if (isset($table->uuid) && $table->uuid == "0b4d53cba2")
```

Comment: I tested your approach. It is not added. I do not need foreach?

Comment: You do of course need the foreach. I just corrected your if statement